# How can the colour under the Row Header in an expanded DataGrid (WPF) Row Details section be changed?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

When a datagrid row is expanded to show the Row Details, is there a way to change the colour of the very left most portion, that inherits the colouring from the parent row?

i.e. this bit: [Row Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lbu7.png)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work it out. The "Main" border being used to colour the normal/alternating row cells, and then a second sub border that handles the events - in this case for Selected/MouseOver_Selected.

Note: The Cyan was because I was testing, it is not a colour scheme choice!!! :-P

**EDIT:**

I have added some additional code, and another Border - I am then using ControlTemplate.Triggers set on multi to preserve the alternating row colours on a standard mouseover, thereby bypassing the visual state mouseover event entirely.

The overall result is to preserves my alternating colouring at all times - except when the row is selected, at which point I am dictating the colouring for the selected row and the row details.

```
<Style x:Key="GridRow"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="NormalBorder"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                             StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                                          Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBorder"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                             Value="Black" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBorder"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                             Value="#BF322828" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal_AlternatingRow">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBorder"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                             Value="Black" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalBorder"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                             Value="#BF642828" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal_Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EventBorder"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                             Value="Green" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EventBorder"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                             Value="Green" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>

                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver_Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EventBorder"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                             Value="Green" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="EventBorder"
                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                             Value="Green" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal_Editing" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver_Editing" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver_Unfocused_Editing" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused_Editing" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused_Selected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver_Unfocused_Selected" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="EventBorder"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                 StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" />
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                                              Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <Border x:Name="AnotherBorder"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                                                  Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                        ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                                          Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"
                                                          SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen,                                           ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical},
                                                      Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, 
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                                   SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                                   Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
                                               ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, 
                                               Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                       Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="AlternationIndex"
                                       Value="0" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="AnotherBorder">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#BF322828"
                                                  Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                       Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="AlternationIndex"
                                       Value="1" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                TargetName="AnotherBorder">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#BF642828"
                                                  Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```